# xml.etree.ElementTree convert double tag to single tag in xml file

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I mean how to convert MyBro tag from double to single with ElementTree?

from: `<MyBro>Steve</MyBro>`

to: `<MyBro Name="Steve" />`

P.S. QS what i did? Searched docs and whole google for info. Might be missing something?

Comment: XSLT would work best here. https://lxml.de/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are parsing an XML file/string and want to replace the nodes with double tag to a single tag. For that, the following solution shall work.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


XML = '''
<Friend>
    <MyBro>
        Foo
    </MyBro>
    <MyBro>
        Bar
    </MyBro>
    <MyBro>
        Lol
    </MyBro> 
</Friend>
'''


# tree = ET.parse(filename)  # if XML from a file
tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(XML))
root = tree.getroot()
ET.indent(root)

for child in root.findall('MyBro'):
    name = child.text.strip()  # get the name enclosed between two tags
    tail = child.tail  # record the original ordering
    child.clear()
    child.set('Name', name)  # use attribute to store name
    child.tail = tail  # restore ordering

print(ET.tostring(root, encoding='unicode'))
```

The output will be

```
<Friend>
  <MyBro Name="Foo" />
  <MyBro Name="Bar" />
  <MyBro Name="Lol" />
</Friend>
```